# How to post a custom header with WebClient.UploadFileAsync in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, file-upload, webclient

I have in my code, a file upload script that needs to post a authentication key header along with the upload. However, it doesn't seem to work like I expected. This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub uploadFile()

    Dim address As String = "http://localhost/stripe/upload.php"

    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim uri As Uri = New Uri(address)

    AddHandler client.UploadFileCompleted, AddressOf UploadFileCompleted
    AddHandler client.UploadProgressChanged, AddressOf UploadProgressCallback

    client.Headers.Set("authKey", login.authKey)
    client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "POST", uploadFileName)

End Sub

Private Sub UploadProgressCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UploadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Label3.Text = String.Format("{0} / {1} kB", Math.Round(e.BytesSent / 1024), Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToSend / 1024))
    Label2.Text = String.Format("{0}%", e.ProgressPercentage)
    Application.DoEvents()
End Sub

Private Sub UploadFileCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UploadFileCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim response As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Result)
    Console.WriteLine(response)
End Sub
```

When I run this piece of code: Nothing happens. There is no line breaks in the output console or anything. Like the code never reached the `UploadFileCompleted` Sub. It doesn't seem to reach the `UploadProgressCallback` either, since the progress bar and the associated labels never update.

When I try to comment out the `client.Headers.Set("authKey", login.authKey)` line: The file seems to upload, but upon completion: I get a 403 Forbidden message as expected because I didn't have the `authKey` header set.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. The problem was caused by `login.authKey` being inaccessible to the thread it was called from. Since the program is multi-threaded: I had to make sure it was accessible to the thread. When I made it accessible: The function worked as expected.

Hope this helps other people behind me. :)